# pandas - load matrix style csv directly to pivottable object

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I have serialized a `pivotTable` object using pandas `.to_csv` function. now i want to load it back to a `pivotTable` object.

The CSV looks something like this, the first column and row are id's

```
        49033   49967   50221   52301
41619               
41665               
46217               
46291   0.002           
47749               
49033           0.001            0.006
49967                    0.03
50221
```

To my knowledge pandas doesn't have any function that can do this for me. Do I have to parse the whole table by myself ?

Comment: What is your code for write to `csv` ? Do you specify separator?

Comment: no, i didn't but that is not a problem, i can easily read my file using pd.read_csv() function, my problem is that it return DataFrame object, i need to get PivotTable object

Comment: `PivotTable object`? in pandas it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [pd.read_fwf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) if you have fixed width format file.

Demo:

```
In [28]: fn = r'D:\temp\.data\1.fwf'

In [29]: pd.read_fwf(fn).fillna('')
Out[29]:
   Unnamed: 0  49033  49967 50221  52301
0       41619
1       41665
2       46217
3       46291  0.002
4       47749
5       49033         0.001        0.006
6       49967                0.03
7       50221
```

If you have a regular CSV file - use [pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Demo:

```
In [32]: pd.read_csv(fn, index_col=0).fillna('')
Out[32]:
            49033       49967      50221       52301       53627      53733       53779      54095       54871      55059     55921  \
41619
41665                                                                        0.00631642
46217
46291  0.00256985                                                             0.0134134
47749                                                             0.0148866
49033              0.00188816             0.00680558  0.00155183             0.00735491             0.00293469  0.0028227
49967                          0.0318261
50221
52301
52465
52621                                                                                                                      0.165127
52851
53407                                                             0.0289802
53437
53627
53733
53779                                                                                    0.0311593
53955
54065

           56007       56163       56287
41619
41665  0.0374982               0.0125017
46217
46291
47749
49033             0.00318618
49967
50221
52301
52465
52621
52851
53407
53437
53627
53733
53779                         0.00455196
53955
54065                          0.0274595
```

Comment: i have CSV file, but function read.csv()  return object type pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, but my csv is in matrix format, is there any way to tell pandas to threat it like matrix style data and return pivot table ?

Comment: @MiroHascic, can you provide a small sample data set (similar to your CSV file) and your desired data set in your question?

Comment: sample of  data in my csv file is in orignal question

Comment: @MiroHascic, does your file look like the one in your question? It has nothing to do with CSV format...

Comment: ow, sorry give my a sec, gonna create small sample file

Comment: thanks for help.. i just found my error, when i loaded csv, i used loc function incorrectly. Is there any way to select whole columns based on header name ? (in example column 49033)